# Life Cycle Http request mode integrate IIS

Tags: request, iis-7.5, application-lifecycle

when we talk about the integrated mode of iis in the life cycle of a request it is mentioned that both the managed and unmanaged modules are executed in each step of the life cycle, those events are not supposed to be part of the httpapplication is there a cycle of own life of the httpapplication and another for the request http?

Answer (score 0):

any request to any resource creates an instance of application manager and this also creates an application domain and that is where the life cycle events are executed in integrated mode where the managed modules coexist as the unmanaged ones. my doubt arose to define the moment in which the domain of application was created, since in the classic mode if there were two pipeline one for resources that are not asp and another for resources asp.net as for example an aspx page.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/bb470252(v=vs.100)